# Script that checks the characters in a variable

Tags: vbscript

I would like to put a security in the edit or variable field so that the first character always represents one letter and the rest of the characters would be only 3 digits.

So: I would like to be able to type a single letter and then some three digits,
K631 or Z987 or T345 etc.

After confirming with the key, the script would check whether the edit field (the variable) contains the required characters if there is no eg the first letter and then 3 digits then the message will be displayed otherwise the message will display the number is correct.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: In what context? Is this an input text field in some HTML/ASP page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of a simple Regex to do so. The regex can be like `^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{3}$` as shown in the following code:

```
strVar = InputBox("Enter the Key")
Set objReg = New RegExp
objReg.Pattern="^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{3}$"      'If you want only the capital letters, you can rewrite the pattern as ^[A-Z][0-9]{3}$ 
If Not objReg.Test(strVar) Then
    MsgBox "Input is incorrect!!!"
Else
    MsgBox "Input is correct"
End If
Set objReg = Nothing
```

> Explanation:
>
> ^ - position just before the start of the string
>
> [a-zA-Z] - character class which matches any lower or upper case alphabet
>
> [0-9] - character class which matches a digit
>
> {3} - will repeat the preceding token 3 times exactly. The preceding token in our case is a
>   number(0-9)
>
> $ - position just after the end of the string

Comment: Hi Gurman, How to do the same thing but only for digits and comma so that you can type in digits and one comma?

Comment: @DagKrus Can you give some valid examples?

Comment: I mean to enter values eg 12,3 lub 1233,4 lub 978,9 lub 21183,4

Values are for kg weight.

They are to be entered only digits and one comma but no more than one comma and can not miss it

Comment: Just replace the pattern in the code with this line: `objReg.Pattern="^\d+,\d$"` [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/YPnzqh/1)

Comment: Hello Gurman. Can you suggest how to do the same for 10 characters? So how to enter the same numbers without letters eg 1234567890